# Prove $d$ and $d'=\frac{d}{1+d}$ are equivalent metrics

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

Suppose $d'(x,y)= \frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ for $x,y \in X$ and I want to prove $d$ and $d'$ are equivalent metrics on $X$.

I would show $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d(x_n,x)=0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d'(x_n,x)=0.$$

To prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d'(x_n,x)=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d(x_n,x)=0$, is it valid to say:

> if $0=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}d'(x_n,x)=\frac{\lim_{n \rightarrow
> > \infty}d(x_n,x)}{1+\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}d(x_n,x)}$,
>
> then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}d(x_n,x)=0$.

If it's invalid, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: No. And what is $y$?

Comment: @amsmath Why isn't that valid? Thanks for pointing out, I just edited my question.

Comment: There is still the $y$... Well, how do you know that $d(x_n,x)$ converges? you can treat the other direction in that way.

Comment: @amsmath do you mind to elaborate? This is following the rules of limits, am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't. You can only do that when you know that $d(x_n,x)$ converges.

Comment: Note that $\tfrac d{1+d} = 1 - \tfrac 1 {1+d}$. That should help.

Comment: Don't get confused by the answers. You are following the right strategy. One direction is as you intended with the other direction: if $d(x_n,x)\to 0$, then $d'(x_n,x) = \tfrac{d(x_n,x)}{1+d(x_n,x)}\to \tfrac 0{1+0} = 0$. For the other direction use the identity in my previous comment.

Comment: @amsmath At that point, it'd be better if you (or someone else, but I'm lazy, and you've been basically paving the way) submitted an answer summarizing and expanding on these comments, since as of now the two answers (including the one deleted) do not address the question.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if $d(x_n,x)\to 0$, then
$$
d'(x_n,x) = \frac{d(x_n,x)}{1+d(x_n,x)}\to \frac 0{1+0} = 0.
$$
Conversely, if $d'(x_n,x)\to 0$, then
$$
0\leftarrow \frac{d(x_n,x)}{1+d(x_n,x)} = 1 - \frac 1 {1+d(x_n,x)}.
$$
That is, you have $\tfrac{1}{1+d(x_n,x)}\to 1$. Taking reciprocals gives $1+d(x_n,x)\to 1$ and thus $d(x_n,x)\to 0$. You can also do the following: $d' = \tfrac d {1+d}$. Solving for $d$ gives $d = \tfrac{d'}{1-d'}$. Hence,
$$
d(x_n,x) = \frac{d'(x_n,x)}{1-d'(x_n,x)}\to\frac 0{1-0} = 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(t)=\frac {t}{1+t}$ is strictly increasing for $t\geq 0.$

If $d'(x_n,x)\to 0$ then there are only finitely many $n$ for which $d(x_n,x)> 1/2$. Because $d(x_n,x)> 1/2\implies d'(x_n,x)=f(d(x_n,x))> f(1/2)=1/3$ and we cannot have $d'(x_n,x)> 1/3$ for infinitely many $n.$

So for all but finitely many $n$ we have $d'(x_n,n)=\frac {d(x_n,x)}{1+d(x_n,x)}\geq \frac {d(x_n,x)}{1+1/2}.$

Hence $d(x_n,x)\leq (1+1/2)d'(x_n,x)$ for all but finitely many $n$, so $d(x_n,x)\to 0.$

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I misunderstood the question - my solution is **not** valid if you are interested in "topological equivalence", rather it's entirely based around a notion called "strong equivalence". I haven't deleted it however, because it could still be useful.

---

To show two metrics $d, d'$ are **strongly** equivalent, it doesn't suffice suffice to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} d(x_n, x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} d'(x_n, x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Consider the integers equipped with the usual metric, $d(a,b)=|a-b|$ and the trivial metric, $d'(a,b) = \cases{0, a=b\\ 1, a\neq b}$

Then your above statement with limits is satisfied, because in each case the sequence $x_n$ is eventually constantly equal to $x$. However, $d$ and $d'$ are not equivalent: Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then there does not exist $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $d(x,y)\leq cd'(x,y)$ for all $y\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

To prove that $d$ and $d'$ are **strongly** equivalent, you want to:

1. choose an arbitrary $x \in X$.
2. Find $c_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $y \in X$, $d(x,y) \leq c_1d'(x,y)$
3. Find $c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $y \in X$, $d'(x,y) \leq c_2d(x,y)$

Comment: Of course, there exists such a $c$, namely $c = 1/2$. Also, what you use here is _strong_ equivalence. Sorry, but your answer is actually not an answer.

Comment: oh you're right - well, $c = 1/2$ doesn't satisfy the condition I wrote out, but that's irrelevant anyway because what you're saying is that for $r = 1/2$ you get the same balls in $\mathbb{Z}$ whichever metric you use

Comment: $d(1,2) = 1 \neq \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}d'(1,2)$

Comment: Yeah, yeah. I mixed $d'$ and $d$. You have $d = 2d'$. You've made another mistake in your last comment.

Comment: all good, thanks for pointing out my mistake though! I'm way too accustomed to spaces with lots of structure so it didn't even occur to me that I was assuming extra information :)

Comment: $d$ and $d'$ are NOT necessarily strongly equivalent . $d'\leq 1$ and $d$  may be  unbounded. Sor example if $X=\Bbb R$ and $d(x,y)=|x-y|.$

Comment: Yeah exactly, I realise my "answer" doesn't address the question because I completely misinterpreted it, but I left it there anyway because it still contains information that could benefit someone else one day. Should I just delete it?

Comment: With your introductory edit in the A,  I suggest you leave it up.